# Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and the progress bar to show a ranking on a leaderboard.

[image: Leaderboard]

Is there a way to customize this to not have it show the "Out of" part?

For example, its technically not progress to complete something, its just a rank that will be shown in the same manner. So really i just wanna be able to remove the box that its filling in but also make it so its round on the right side as well.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish

[image]

As a side question, any idea how to remove the padding on the div the progress bar is in so it aligns in the middle like the other content?

Comment: The progress bar is just the bar. Any other text will need to be added directly into your HTML

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I just dont want to background of the progress bar (the empty part) to show up. So in short, the part that is filled up needs to just be the width of the progress bar so it is always "100%" but shorter based on percent

Comment: Why didn't you say that then instead of *"out of" part*? Just use CSS to remove the border and background colour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.progress {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

table .progress {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

See demo here (thanks Ohgodwhy) - http://jsfiddle.net/r4zkv/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just override the bootstrap .progress class styles:

```
.progress {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.progress-bar {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Make sure you do not alter the bootstrap.css file directly, just add the above style to your site.css file which should always come after bootstrap.css in any project so you can override bootstrap default styles for that custom look.