# Bootstrap Progress bar Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 with a progress bar and I am trying to align the bar vertically within the table cell. I was able to get the other cells valigned to the middle but the bar int moving. How can I remove all that extra space from the progress bar div?

[image]

```
<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="75" style="width: 60%;">$60 of $75 limit</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution... on a question I had asked before ironically.

[Bootstrap Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135164/bootstrap-progress-bar)